# Dropdown menu shows me as not logged in while on mobile site for community I didn't join

Tags: bug, login, mobile-web, stack-exchange-button

I used my SE login to log into my account on my mobile browser, and I have not had any trouble using the drop-down menu while on it to access my different communities. The drop-down menu "knows" that I am logged in.

However, I recently noticed, while on Programming and Puzzling SE, where I do not have an account, that the drop-down menu treats me as logged out. I checked one or two other sites where I do not have an account and ran into the same behaviour. At the same time though, I am still able to access my inbox and reputation tracker on these sites where I do not have an account.

[image: screenshot]

**Note**: I don't have this problem on the desktop site though: I can see a logout option and my list of communities on the drop-down menu even on sites where I don't have a profile.

Answer (score 1):

> while on Programming and Puzzling SE, where I do not have an account, that the drop-down menu treats me as logged out

Yes. Because on those sites, where you do not have a profile, you *are* anonymous / logged out.

The top-bar still *knows* who you are, but the site itself doesn't.

Comment: I don't have this problem on the desktop site though: I can see a logout option and my list of communities on the drop-down menu even on sites where I don't have a profile.

Comment: Yeah, this is probably just an oversight in the mobile views.